# How come this line of code returns me an "undefined" then followed by a value

Tags: javascript, html

How come method equal always returns with an "undefined" followed by a number? 
and when I try to parse it. it returns me a NaN.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
 <head>
 <script>

var fnum;
var secondNum;
var operation;

function msg(val) {

document.getElementById("fnumtext").value += val;
fnum += val;
}
function showOperation(oper) 
{
    document.getElementById("fnumtext").value = "";
    document.getElementById("operation").value = oper;
    operation = oper;
}

function equal() {
    secondNum = document.getElementById("fnumtext").value;
    alert(fnum);    
}

 </script>
 </head>
  <body>
    <input id = "fnumtext"type="text" name="firstnum" /><br />
    <input id = "operation" type="text" name="secondnum" /><br />
    <input type="button" value="1" onclick="msg('1')" />
    <input type="button" value="2" onclick="msg('2')" />
    <input type="button" value="3" onclick="msg('3')" /></br>
    <input type="button" value="4" onclick="msg('4')" />
    <input type="button" value="5" onclick="msg('5')" />
    <input type="button" value="6" onclick="msg('6')" /><br/>
    <input type="button" value="7" onclick="msg('7')" />
    <input type="button" value="8" onclick="msg('8')" />
    <input type="button" value="9" onclick="msg('9')" /></br>
    <input type="button" value="0" onclick="msg('0')" /></br>
    <input type="button" value="+" onclick="showOperation('+')" />
    <input type="button" value="*" onclick="showOperation('*')" />
    <input type="button" value="/" onclick="showOperation('/')" />
    <input type="button" value="-" onclick="showOperation('-')" />
    <input type="button" value="=" onclick="equal()" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What methods? What returns? This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @GGG when I call the "equal" method it alerts an undefined + the value in the textbox. Check it, it has been edited

Comment: It is because the fnum+=val would return the string 'undefined+<value>'. You can fix this by initializing fnum to 0.

Comment: @Scorpion-Prince but when I try to press  4 and 5 instead of 45 it gives me random value why is that? I am going to parse it as a number

Comment: If you just want the number the user entered in the firstNum text box, why don't you just read the text box value in the equals function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `val` variable in the `msg()` function is inputted as a string. So when you attempt to do `+=`, it treats its original value as a string so you end up doing `'undefined' + <some integer>` creating your effect.

Try removing the single quotes from all your function calls in your onclick events, and *just* send the integer. Also, you should define `var fnum = 0;` rather than just declaring the variable if you want to use the `+=` operator.

Comment: but what if I try to press 2 digit numbers? like 55?

Comment: @user962206: I'm not going to sit here and build the whole thing for you. Your question was only about the "undefined" part. It's pretty obvious that the stage you're at right now only adds each number you press to the total and the operators don't even do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You call "alert" with "fnum" variable as param. It can be undefined if you press "equal" before pressing any other button

Comment: function equal() {
    secondNum = document.getElementById("fnumtext").value;
    alert(fnum);    - here fnum can be undefined if you click on your "Equal" button before clicking any other button
}